# Class not found exception in Apache NetBeans jdk version 17,but I'm adding jar file but they still, how to resolve it plz help me

Tags: java, mssql-jdbc

Class not found exception in jdk Class not found exception in jdk 17 apache NetBeans
.Class not found exception in jdk 17 apache NetBeans.
.Class not found exception in jdk 17 apache NetBeans.Class not found exception in jdk 17 apache NetBeans